# Split a string by commas except when the comma is part of the sentence

Tags: java

I have strings like this

```
"'Hello, how are you?','string',123"
```

I need to split it so it looks like

```
["'Hello, how are you'", "'string'", "123"]
```

But when I use String.split(","), I get this:

```
["'Hello", "how are you'","'string'","123"]
```

How can I split by comma but only when it's not between single quotes?

Comment: I guess you have to look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing then. I think: too broad for a simple question here.

Comment: @yshavit yes i can use a third party parser but it isn't JSON

Comment: not really even language processing, just a boolean for "am I in a quote right now?" and an iteration of the string (using a StringBuilder)

Comment: You will need your own split function. you need to maintain a bool for the within qoutes, so you know if you ignore your comma or not.

Comment: @Rogue maybe, maybe not. Maybe the 6K reputation of the questioner made me think that his problem can't be that trivial ;-)